# What are the dangers of using 3g/4g in smartphones?

Tags: man-in-the-middle, mobile, sniffing, gsm, cellular

Since we should always avoid public networks, is there some sort of attack that intercept my online activity or steal passwords when I'm using 3g/4g? If exists, how I can protect myself from this type of attack? My device is not rooted, if it matters.

Comment: If you click on the `gsm` tag, you will get some excellent questions around cellular security.

Comment: "What are the dangers" is too broad a question to answer. If you're wondering simply whether or not MITM attacks are possible with 3G/4G, _that_ is something that can be answered.

Comment: @forest I would like to know which attacks are more common in 3g/4g in smartphones and how defend against them.

Comment: I don't think any attacks are _common_. However, if you're referring to stingray-type interception, I'm afraid there is nothing you can do to prevent it. While 3G/4G is more secure than older GSM protocols in that respect, it's still possible to intercept them and act as a man-in-the-middle attacker.

Comment: Thank you, forest. Actually, I'm new in this subject and I don't know any attacks, so I was not referring to anything. Since you said that any attacks are _common_ , is there another attacks you think that I should know? I'm not considering governments or anything like this, just bad guys.

Comment: @Mycroft Just use HTTPS on websites whenever you can, and beware phishing sites. This is standard advice for using the internet in general, but it also applies to cellular networks.

Comment: My principal doubt is if is safe to use apps with sensitive data when using 3g/4g. How i can be sure that these connections are https since I can't see them?

Comment: @Mycroft You don't have any easy way to know that, so it really depends on how sensitive that data is. Many 3G/4G connections use a 64-bit cipher, which is not extremely secure.

Comment: Well, consider sensitive data like social media and even bank accounts

Comment: @Mycroft The amount of money required to break a 64-bit cipher is larger than the amount of money someone would likely gain from defrauding your bank with your bank details. I think you're safe.

Comment: If you mean 64-bit symmetric passwords I suppose that depends on the algorithm used, the key entropy, the effective bits and some other factors. I would not say 64-bit security per se will make you "safe"